# Hive Parquet Table simple select command ending up with error

Tags: hive, parquet, snappy

I have a Parquet table in Hive (within Cloudera cluster and this is an External Table). When I execute **select * from table_name** command, it is working fine

But when I try to see the values of a particular column, I am getting the outofmemory error even though I limit the results to be just 10.

```
select col_name from table_name limit 10;
```

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>
> FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask.
>   Java heap space

Really weird . I am new to Parquet. So appreciating any of your help on this. Thanks

Additional Info of the Hive table retrieved from **desc table** command :

```
# Storage Information        
SerDe Library:          org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe  
InputFormat:            org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat    
OutputFormat:           org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat   
Compressed:             No                       
Num Buckets:            -1                       
Bucket Columns:         []                       
Sort Columns:           []                       
Storage Desc Params:         
    serialization.format    1
```

Comment: which client are you using to execute the query?

Comment: I am using Hive CLI